Did Gambit and Rogue have children?
Eventually, Gambit  and Rogue  married, but I didn't find out if they had children. Moreover, while the children of Cyclops (Scott Summers) and Jean Grey are "famous" and have a very strong impact on the future and storyline, I didn't find anything about Gambit and Rogue's children.

Yes, but in alternate universes/timelines
In X-Men: The End they have two children.

X-Men: The End is a 2004-2006 trilogy of miniseries published by Marvel Comics, detailing the last days of the X-Men and their adventures in an alternative future. The series, which was part of Marvel's The End line of books, was written by Chris Claremont and drawn by Sean Chen, with cover art by Greg Land and Gene Ha.

Rebecca LeBeau and Oliver LeBeau
Rebecca

She is an Omega Level Mutant, who possesses her father's kinetic-based powers but on a stronger level.

Oliver

​He inherited his mother's ability to absorb powers. He can fly and has permanently absorbed telepathy, though he does not like this power. He also possesses a degree of his father's hypnotic ability.


In X-Men 2099 they (probably) have a son called Arcadian.

X-Men 2099 is a comic book series published by Marvel Comics from 1993 to 1996 that chronicled the adventures of an X-Men team in the year 2099. It extends the Marvel 2099 imprint, which features other future versions of popular Marvel characters, such as Spider-Man 2099 and Hulk 2099. The series was written by John Francis Moore and largely pencilled by Ron Lim.

Arcadian

In this alternate universe of Marvel, the X-Men fight against an intelligent group of undead zombies. The son of Gambit and Rogue, Arcadian, is one of the undead. It never specifically states that he is their son, but their is STRONG evidence that he is the son of those two. He speaks with a Cajun/Southern drawl accent, wears a trench coat, and has red eyes. He uses a deck of tarot cards that are plasma-charged and throws them. He calls them Death cards. He also fights with a bo-staff. He returned to being dead when the X-Men defeated the boss, Graverobber. Arcadian originally died around 2040

